# Change an external jar (hot deployment) during execution of Spark Streaming

Tags: apache-spark, jar

A spark streaming application should leverage (via a facade) a DSL, which during runtime is available either as generated java coding or byte code (ANTLR) and is ideally deployed via a separate jar to the Spark worker nodes.

Is it technical possible and feasible to exchange the jar, containing the generated DSL ? That is the spark streaming application would not be stopped but the logic (DSL) changed on the fly. You might think that it is possible to exchange the jars on the Spark worker nodes and load the jars again...but due to the distributed nature of Spark I have no clue if this approach would end in a mess.

So is there any concept of 'hot deployment' of external artifacts in Spark or is this simply out of scope?